# Rails migration issue column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, psql

I have simple migration for add column

```
class AddSeatGroupForFee < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :fees, :seat_group_id, :integer
  end
end
```

my `Fee` model

```
belongs_to :seat_group
```

my `SeatGroup`

```
has_many :fees
```

and when i want to use this column in next migration
i haven't this column

when i stop with `binding.pry`

```
seat_group_id
```

should be presents

Fee

```
=> Fee(id: integer, code: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

and `Fee` hasn't `seat_group_id` column here

```
world_business = SeatGroup.create({name: '(name)', airline_code: 'code'})
world_business.fees.where(code: 'W-BUSINESS') => error here
```

why it happens?

rails 4

Answer (score 0):

```
Fee.reset_column_information
```

fixed my problem